# Why does an antenna sometimes has a bending on the end of the wire?

Tags: antenna

I sometimes see antennas as follows ( Paint ;) ):

[image]

It sometimes is even in manufactured wires. This gives the clue that there is a scientific explanation for this bending. I have searched on the internet, but could not really find a good answer on it. Can somebody please explain to me if this is true and has a function or has no impact or maybe is worse for the signal.

Comment: On RC toys I used to think it was because a sharp, somewhat rigid, steel wire pointing up close to a kids eye is not a terrible good idea of a safety thing.

Comment: it is because antennas are delicate, they are Co-Axial, this is also to establish a higher surface area on the outer layer of the CoAx. also because they can sometimes be sharp or metal, to reduce the risk of injury.

Comment: @ricardomenzer Or was it because at 27MHz the 2.78meter long, straight stick would not be a great property for a 30cm remote control toy? :-P

Comment: @Asmyldof might as well use a wired controller at that point :)

Comment: @Asmyldof I was actually talking about the few millimeters rounding bend in the antenna tip. I don't think that extra length would make a huge difference in the performance of a regular Chinese toy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good reason to put such a loop on the end of the monopole antenna is to reduce the likelihood of someone being stabbed by accidentally falling on or tripping into the antenna.   Under all ordinary circumstances, it would have no discernible effect on the performance of the antenna when compared to the same antenna with the small loop uncurled.